# How can I pass parameters to route with navigate function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation

Is there a way to pass some parameters to a route with the navigate function is react? I found the below approach, but it doesn't work since the route parameter in the second file is undefined.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const exploreTopic = () =>{
    navigate(`/topic/${props.id}`,{id:props.id});
};

return(
  <div onClick={exploreTopic}>smth</div>
)
```

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import './style.css'

const SingleTopic = ({route,navigate}) => {
  return (
    <div>
        {route.params.id}
    </div>
  )
}

export default SingleTopic
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass the data this way

```
const exploreTopic = () =>{
    navigate(`/topic/${props.id}`,{state:{id:props.id}});
};
```

And your SingleTopic will become

```
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';

const SingleTopic = ({route,navigate}) => {
 const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <div>
        {location.state.id}
    </div>
  )
}

export default SingleTopic
```

Comment: looks nice, but I do not understand the other missing bit  Route element. In my code the error is - No routes matched location "/order"  for path path='/order/:id'  and call    navigate(`/order/${order.id}`,{state:{id:order.id}});

Answer (score 0):

use `useLocation`:

```
const exploreTopic = () =>{
    navigate(`/topic/${props.id}`,{state:{id:props.id}});
};
```

you can remove the elements `{route,navigate}` from the `SingleTopic` component:

```
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';

function SingleTopic(){
 const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <div>
        {location.state.id}
    </div>
  )
}

export default SingleTopic
```